# ¿Cómo obtengo el total del curso de los usuarios de una cohorte -- Moodle 3.11.6+?

Tags: php, mysql, moodle

¿Cómo obtengo la calificación final de los integrantes de una cohorte?

Tengo la siguiente consulta, pero las filas se repiten y solo obtengo las calificaciones de los elementos:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT u.firstname, u.lastname, ROUND(g.finalgrade,2) 
FROM mdl_cohort AS h 
JOIN mdl_cohort_members AS hm ON hm.cohortid = h.id 
JOIN mdl_user AS u ON u.id = hm.userid 
JOIN mdl_user_enrolments AS ue ON ue.userid = hm.id 
JOIN mdl_grade_grades AS g ON g.userid = hm.id 
JOIN mdl_grade_items AS gi ON gi.id = g.itemid 
JOIN mdl_enrol AS e ON e.id = ue.enrolid 
JOIN mdl_role_assignments AS ra ON ra.userid = hm.id 
JOIN mdl_context AS ct ON ct.id = ra.contextid AND ct.contextlevel = 50 
JOIN mdl_course AS c ON c.id = ct.instanceid AND e.courseid = c.id 
WHERE gi.itemtype = 'course' ORDER BY u.lastname

Desde ya muchas gracias

[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/l7NXK.png
```